# have binomial tests for all combinations in a matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'm trying to calculate all the combination of Binomial test in a matrix in r. Is there any way that I can achieve that without manually enter all data from the matrix?

the matrix

```
      reject    accept
A      121        5
B       63        16
C       32        86
```

I can do

```
A <- binom.test(121, 126, p=0.5)
B <- binom.test(63, 79, p=0.5)
...
```

But it is repetitive and time-consuming.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `apply(M, 1, function(x) binom.test(x, p=0.5))`

Comment: `Map(binom.test, m[, 'reject'], rowSums(m))`

Comment: @CPak thx for your comment, what is `x` here?

Comment: @Kay: `x` is the 2-element vector of each row (I'm assuming your data format is matrix).  From the documentation, you can pass a 2-element vector to `binom.test` - `x represents 
number of successes, or a vector of length 2 giving the numbers of successes and failures, respectively.` I realize now that you might have to flip the column order of your matrix with `M <- M[,2:1]` before doing this.